# How can I convert the code from Mathematica to text and put it in enumerate like this?

Tags: export, latex

I have a list

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 
1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 
1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2,2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}
```

I would like to convert that list to get text file to compile text file like this

[image]

I posted my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708066/how-can-i-convert-the-code-from-mathematica-to-text-and-put-it-in-enumerate-like)
because, I think text can solve this question.

How can I tell Mathematica convert my list to text file so I can put text file to

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cross posted to [tex.se]  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708066/how-can-i-convert-the-code-from-mathematica-to-text-and-put-it-in-enumerate-like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lis = {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1,
      2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 
     1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 
     2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 
     2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 
     1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 
     2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 
     2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 
     1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 
     1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 
     2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 
     2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 
     2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 
     1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 
     1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 
     2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 
     2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 
     1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 
     2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 
     2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 
     1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 
     1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 
     1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 
     2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 
     2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 
     1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}};
```

Now

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "main.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[file, "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <>
   "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <>
   "\\begin{document}\n" <>
   "\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];

Do[z = ToString[lis[[n, 1]]] <> "," <> ToString[lis[[n, 2]]];
  z = StringReplace[z, "{" -> "\\{"];
  z = StringReplace[z, "}" -> "\\}"];
  WriteString[file, "\\item " <> z <> "\n"],
  {n, 1, Length@lis}
  ];
WriteString[file, "\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]
```

Generates the tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 1, 2\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 1\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{1, 2, 2\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 1\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 1, 2\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 1\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{1, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{1, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{1, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{1, 2, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{2, 1, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{2, 1, 2\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{2, 2, 1\}
\item \{2, 2, 2\},\{2, 2, 2\}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles to PDF file:

[image]

Note that you have to escape the `{` and `}` in Latex, else they will be lost. If you actually want this, then remove the two lines

```
z = StringReplace[z, "{" -> "\\{"];
z = StringReplace[z, "}" -> "\\}"];
```

In the code above. This will now generate this .tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item {1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1}
\item {1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 2}
\item {1, 1, 1},{1, 2, 1}
\item {1, 1, 1},{1, 2, 2}
\item {1, 1, 1},{2, 1, 1}
\item {1, 1, 1},{2, 1, 2}
\item {1, 1, 1},{2, 2, 1}
\item {1, 1, 1},{2, 2, 2}
\item {1, 1, 2},{1, 1, 1}
\item {1, 1, 2},{1, 1, 2}
\item {1, 1, 2},{1, 2, 1}
\item {1, 1, 2},{1, 2, 2}
\item {1, 1, 2},{2, 1, 1}
\item {1, 1, 2},{2, 1, 2}
\item {1, 1, 2},{2, 2, 1}
\item {1, 1, 2},{2, 2, 2}
\item {1, 2, 1},{1, 1, 1}
\item {1, 2, 1},{1, 1, 2}
\item {1, 2, 1},{1, 2, 1}
\item {1, 2, 1},{1, 2, 2}
\item {1, 2, 1},{2, 1, 1}
\item {1, 2, 1},{2, 1, 2}
\item {1, 2, 1},{2, 2, 1}
\item {1, 2, 1},{2, 2, 2}
\item {1, 2, 2},{1, 1, 1}
\item {1, 2, 2},{1, 1, 2}
\item {1, 2, 2},{1, 2, 1}
\item {1, 2, 2},{1, 2, 2}
\item {1, 2, 2},{2, 1, 1}
\item {1, 2, 2},{2, 1, 2}
\item {1, 2, 2},{2, 2, 1}
\item {1, 2, 2},{2, 2, 2}
\item {2, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1}
\item {2, 1, 1},{1, 1, 2}
\item {2, 1, 1},{1, 2, 1}
\item {2, 1, 1},{1, 2, 2}
\item {2, 1, 1},{2, 1, 1}
\item {2, 1, 1},{2, 1, 2}
\item {2, 1, 1},{2, 2, 1}
\item {2, 1, 1},{2, 2, 2}
\item {2, 1, 2},{1, 1, 1}
\item {2, 1, 2},{1, 1, 2}
\item {2, 1, 2},{1, 2, 1}
\item {2, 1, 2},{1, 2, 2}
\item {2, 1, 2},{2, 1, 1}
\item {2, 1, 2},{2, 1, 2}
\item {2, 1, 2},{2, 2, 1}
\item {2, 1, 2},{2, 2, 2}
\item {2, 2, 1},{1, 1, 1}
\item {2, 2, 1},{1, 1, 2}
\item {2, 2, 1},{1, 2, 1}
\item {2, 2, 1},{1, 2, 2}
\item {2, 2, 1},{2, 1, 1}
\item {2, 2, 1},{2, 1, 2}
\item {2, 2, 1},{2, 2, 1}
\item {2, 2, 1},{2, 2, 2}
\item {2, 2, 2},{1, 1, 1}
\item {2, 2, 2},{1, 1, 2}
\item {2, 2, 2},{1, 2, 1}
\item {2, 2, 2},{1, 2, 2}
\item {2, 2, 2},{2, 1, 1}
\item {2, 2, 2},{2, 1, 2}
\item {2, 2, 2},{2, 2, 1}
\item {2, 2, 2},{2, 2, 2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But the above will now generate this PDF file which I do not think this is what you want:

[image]

> Intead output \item {1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1}. How can I get \item (1,
> 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)

Replace the two lines in the original code to the this

```
z = StringReplace[z, "{" -> "("];
z = StringReplace[z, "}" -> ")"];
```

And now main.tex looks like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item (1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 1),(1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1),(1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 1, 1),(2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1),(2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 1),(2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1),(2, 2, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2),(1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2),(1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2),(1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2),(1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2),(2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2),(2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2),(2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2),(2, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1),(1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1),(1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1),(1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1),(1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1),(2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1),(2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1),(2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1),(2, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2),(1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2),(1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2),(1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2),(1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2),(2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2),(2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2),(2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2),(2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1),(1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1),(1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1),(1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1),(2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1),(2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1),(2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1),(2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2),(1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2),(1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2),(1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2),(1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2),(2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2),(2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2),(2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2),(2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1),(1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1),(1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1),(1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1),(1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1),(2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1),(2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1),(2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1),(2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2),(1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2),(1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2),(1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2),(1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2),(2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2),(2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2),(2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2),(2, 2, 2)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> or \item (1, 1, 1), \quad (1, 1, 1)

Replace The loop to this

```
Do[z = ToString[lis[[n, 1]]] <> ", \\quad " <> ToString[lis[[n, 2]]];
  z = StringReplace[z, "{" -> "("];
  z = StringReplace[z, "}" -> ")"];
  WriteString[file, "\\item " <> z <> "\n"],
  {n, 1, Length@lis}
  ];
```

And now main.tex looks like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 1, 2), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 1), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (1, 2, 2), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 1), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 1, 2), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 1), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (1, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (1, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (1, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (1, 2, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (2, 1, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (2, 1, 2)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (2, 2, 1)
\item (2, 2, 2), \quad (2, 2, 2)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Basically, anything you can do in Latex, you can generate from Mathematica. I generate most of my large PDF files this way. I have many large PDF files over 100,000 pages all generated programmatically like this. You just need to escape the Latex commands and know little Latex, and the rest is just Mathematica coding.

Comment: Intead output `\item \{1, 1, 1\},\{1, 1, 1\}`. How can I get `\item (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1) ` or `\item (1, 1, 1), \quad (1, 1, 1) `?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter fyi, updated.