# How can I convert a list containing three points and its equation passing three points to text file?

Tags: export, latex

I have a lis

```
{{{-12,2,-1},{-11,1,-5},{-10,-2,3},10 x+6 y+z+109==0},{{-12,2,-1},{-11,1,-5},{-10,6,3},2 x-2 y+z+29==0},{{-12,2,-1},{-11,1,-5},{-9,5,-7},3 x-y+z+39==0}}
```

I would like to conver lis to text file has the form

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $A(-12,2,-1)$, \quad $B(-11,1,-5)$, \quad $C(-10,-2,3)$, \quad $(P):10 x+6 y+z+109=0$.
\item $A(-12,2,-1)$, \quad $B(-11,1,-5)$, \quad $C(-10,6,3)$, \quad $(P):2 x-2 y+z+29=0$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Base on [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297097/how-can-i-convert-the-code-from-mathematica-to-text-and-put-it-in-enumerate-like)

I tried

```
lis={{{-12,2,-1},{-11,1,-5},{-10,-2,3},10 x+6 y+z+109==0},{{-12,2,-1},{-11,1,-5},{-10,6,3},2 x-2 y+z+29==0},{{-12,2,-1},{-11,1,-5},{-9,5,-7},3 x-y+z+39==0}}
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName=FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"plane.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName],DeleteFile[fileName]];
file=OpenWrite[fileName,PageWidth->Infinity];
WriteString[file,"\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n"<>"\\usepackage{enumitem}\n"<>"\\begin{document}\n"<>"\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];

Do[z=ToString[lis[[n,1]]]<>", \\quad "<>ToString[lis[[n,2]]];
z=StringReplace[z,"{"->"$("];
z=StringReplace[z,"}"->")$"];
WriteString[file,"\\item "<>z<>"\n"],{n,1,Length@lis}];
WriteString[file,"\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]
```

I only get

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $(-12, 2, -1)$, \quad $(-11, 1, -5)$
\item $(-12, 2, -1)$, \quad $(-11, 1, -5)$
\item $(-12, 2, -1)$, \quad $(-11, 1, -5)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code generates this PDF

[image]

Code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
lis = {
  {{-12, 2, -1}, {-11, 1, -5}, {-10, -2, 3}, 
   10 x + 6 y + z + 109 == 0},
  {{-12, 2, -1}, {-11, 1, -5}, {-10, 6, 3}, 2 x - 2 y + z + 29 == 0},
  {{-12, 2, -1}, {-11, 1, -5}, {-9, 5, -7}, 3 x - y + z + 39 == 0}
  }

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "main.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[file, "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <>
   "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <>
   "\\begin{document}\n" <>
   "\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];

format[e_List] := ("A" <> ToString[e[[1]]] <> ",\\quad B" <> 
    ToString[e[[2]]] <> ",\\quad C" <> ToString[e[[3]]] <> 
    ",\\quad (P) : $" <> ToString[TeXForm[e[[4]]]] <> "$");
Do[myTMP = format[lis[[n]]];
  myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "{" -> "("];
  myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "}" -> ")"];
  WriteString[file, "\\item " <> myTMP <> "\n"],
  {n, 1, Length@lis}
  ];
WriteString[file, "\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]
```

Latex file generated

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item A(-12, 2, -1),\quad B(-11, 1, -5),\quad C(-10, -2, 3),\quad (P) : $10 x+6 y+z+109=0$
\item A(-12, 2, -1),\quad B(-11, 1, -5),\quad C(-10, 6, 3),\quad (P) : $2 x-2 y+z+29=0$
\item A(-12, 2, -1),\quad B(-11, 1, -5),\quad C(-9, 5, -7),\quad (P) : $3 x-y+z+39=0$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

To make each field Math, you can use this version

[image]

Code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
lis = {
  {{-12, 2, -1}, {-11, 1, -5}, {-10, -2, 3}, 
   10 x + 6 y + z + 109 == 0},
  {{-12, 2, -1}, {-11, 1, -5}, {-10, 6, 3}, 2 x - 2 y + z + 29 == 0},
  {{-12, 2, -1}, {-11, 1, -5}, {-9, 5, -7}, 3 x - y + z + 39 == 0}
  }

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "main.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[file, "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <>
   "\\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.2in]{geometry}\n" <>
   "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <>
   "\\begin{document}\n" <>
   "\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];

format[e_List] := ("$A" <> ToString[e[[1]]] <> "$,\\quad $B" <> 
    ToString[e[[2]]] <> "$,\\quad $C" <> ToString[e[[3]]] <> 
    "$,\\quad $(P) : " <> ToString[TeXForm[e[[4]]]] <> "$");
Do[myTMP = format[lis[[n]]];
  myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "{" -> "("];
  myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "}" -> ")"];
  WriteString[file, "\\item " <> myTMP <> "\n"],
  {n, 1, Length@lis}
  ];
WriteString[file, "\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]
```

Which generates this latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $A(-12, 2, -1)$,\quad $B(-11, 1, -5)$,\quad $C(-10, -2, 3)$,\quad $(P) : 10 x+6 y+z+109=0$
\item $A(-12, 2, -1)$,\quad $B(-11, 1, -5)$,\quad $C(-10, 6, 3)$,\quad $(P) : 2 x-2 y+z+29=0$
\item $A(-12, 2, -1)$,\quad $B(-11, 1, -5)$,\quad $C(-9, 5, -7)$,\quad $(P) : 3 x-y+z+39=0$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use mathmode instead TeXForm?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter  what is `mathmode` ?  I never seen this function in Mathematica. `TeXForm` is used to convert mathematica math expressions to Latex in Mathematica. Since the 4th field in your list is an question, I used `TeXForm` on it.

Comment: Please see my text file.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter fyi, updated. Hopefully this is what you meant.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to copy premable of tex file to Mathematica file and put at `WriteString` and it is formated automatically?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter it will be better to put the preamble you want to use into an external small .tex file. Then you can just use `\input{my_file}` and this will automatically load the file when latex is run.