# Unable to get proper Latex format from Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting, latex

Based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297104/how-can-i-convert-a-list-containing-three-points-and-its-equation-passing-three), I tried this code

```
    Clear["Global`*"]
    list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {m, n}} /. 
       Solve[{(a + c)/2 == m, (b + d)/2 == n, -5 <= a <= 5, -5 <= b <= 
          5, -5 <= c <= 5, -5 <= d <= 5, a > c, a  b  c  d  m  n != 0, 
         a != b != c != d, a ∈ Integers, b ∈ Integers, 
         c ∈ Integers, d ∈ Integers, 
         m ∈ Rationals, n ∈ Rationals, 
         m ∉ Integers && n ∉ Integers  }, {a, b, 
         c, d, m, n}];
    pM = {x, y};
    lis = list[[1 ;; 5]]
```

and got
[image]

When I tried,

```
    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
    fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "test.tex"}]
    If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
    file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
    WriteString[file, 
      "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <> 
       "\\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.2in]{geometry}\n" <> 
       "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <> "\\begin{document}\n" <> 
       "\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];
    
    format[e_List] := ("$A" <> ToString[e[[1]]] <> "$,\\quad $B" <> 
        ToString[e[[2]]] <> "$,\\quad $M" <> ToString[e[[3]]] <> "$");
    Do[myTMP = format[lis[[n]]];
      myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "{" -> "("];
      myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "}" -> ")"];
      WriteString[file, "\\item " <> myTMP <> "\n"], {n, 1, Length@lis}];
    WriteString[file, "\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
    Close[file]
```

I got the text file,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $A(-4, -3)$,\quad $B(-5, -2)$,\quad $M   9     5
(-(-), -(-))
   2     2$
\item $A(-4, -3)$,\quad $B(-5, 2)$,\quad $M   9     1
(-(-), -(-))
   2     2$
\item $A(-4, -3)$,\quad $B(-5, 4)$,\quad $M   9   1
(-(-), -)
   2   2$
\item $A(-4, -2)$,\quad $B(-5, -3)$,\quad $M   9     5
(-(-), -(-))
   2     2$
\item $A(-4, -2)$,\quad $B(-5, -1)$,\quad $M   9     3
(-(-), -(-))
   2     2$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: change `ToString[e[[2]]]` to `ToString[InputForm@e[[2]]]` and same for the other one `e[[3]]` if you do not use `inputForm` you can get 2D strings which messes up things.

Comment: Thanks. How can I present `$M(-9/2, -5/2)$` has the form `$M(-\dfrac{9}{2},-\dfrac{5}{2})$`?

Comment: But what is `M(-9/2, -5/2)` in Mathematica? This is not valid expression in Mathematica. If you are trying to generate this in Latex you'd have to do it manually.  Like this `ToString@TeXForm[M] <> "\\left(" <> ToString@TeXForm[-9/2] <> "," <>  ToString@TeXForm[-5/2] <> "\\right)"`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuFCZ.png) since you can't use `TeXForm` on the whole thing, You can only use `TeXForm` on valid Mathematica expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TeXForm` can be used to convert the lists, or any Mathematica expression, to LaTeX.  In this case you may want use `TeXForm` with `MatrixForm`, like this

```
format = ToString @* TeXForm @* MatrixForm;

enum = "\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n" <>
   "\\item $$A = " <> format[list[[1]]] <> "$$\n" <>
   "\\item $$B = " <> format[list[[2]]] <> "$$\n" <>
   "\\item $$C = " <> format[list[[3]]] <> "$$\n" <>
   "\\item $$D = " <> format[list[[4]]] <> "$$\n" <>
   "\\item $$M = " <> format[list[[5]]] <> "$$\n" <>
   "\\end{enumerate}\n"
```

This should produce the LaTeX needed to give a nice looking result in your document.  Here's a screenshot

[image]

Other pieces of the document are

```
beginDoc =  "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <>
      "\\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.2in]{geometry}\n" <>
         "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <>
         "\\begin{document}\n" ; 

endDoc="\\end{document}\n";
```

Instead of doing the whole Open-Write-Close routine, you may want to use

```
Export[fileName, beginDoc <> enum <> endDoc, "Text"]
```

Comment: Please post full your code. I don't know how past your code in my document.